# Total IP to CIDR Conversion

Tags: ip, subnet

I know Start IP Address aka Network Id and also total IP Address as well but how I can calculate its CIDR or End IP from it without knowing Subnet Mask.

**Example**

```
Start IP : 192.168.8.0
Total IP : 1024
```

Answer (score 0):

1024 IP addresses is a /22  CIDR and the network mask would be 255.255.252.0

You can go to http://ipconvertertools.com/cidr2ipranges and convert 192.168.8.0/22 to IP range.

You will get:

```
Network Address  First IP   Last IP       Subnet Mask       Broadcast   Total IP's
192.168.8.0 192.168.8.1 192.168.11.254  255.255.252.0   192.168.11.255  1021
```

Just add few IP's so you will have 1024 total IP

How to convert manually:
Convert IP to binary -> 11000000101010000000100000000000
Convert total IP -> 10000000000

```
======
11000000101010000000100000000000 +
                     10000000000 = 
----------------------------------
11000000101010000000110000000000 = 192.168.12.0
```

(where is 0 remains zero. If in the same column there is 1, it becomes 1)

Comment: thank you sir, I know online calculation methods but need calculation method not solution that from where I can calculate it :)

Comment: You can transform the IP to binary. Transform the total IP (1024) to binary. Add these two numbers. And convert back the result to IP address. You should get 192.168.12.0

Comment: Hi Thanks Again,  I have these Binary Numbers for IP Address, (192)11000000 -
(168)10101000 -
(8)00001000 -
(0)00000000 and I have also tried to convert 1024 to Decimal from online converter (as I don't know how to do it manually) and its , (1024)10000000000 . Now, how to Add these :)

Comment: I've added it in my answer